# Springboot microservice not showing up in Jaeger UI

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, jaeger

I have a micro service and added the jaeger config for tracing. Unable to see the service in the jaeger UI. Jaeger UI shows up only default service.

Step 1 - Below is the config that I created for jaeger.

```
    return new io.jaegertracing.Configuration("test-client")
        .withSampler(new io.jaegertracing.Configuration.SamplerConfiguration().withType(ConstSampler.TYPE)
            .withParam(1))
        .withReporter(new io.jaegertracing.Configuration.ReporterConfiguration().withLogSpans(true))
        .getTracer();
```

Step 2 - After installing local docker, did run the below command.

```
docker run -d --name jaeger \
  -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HOST_PORT=:9411 \
  -p 5775:5775/udp \
  -p 6831:6831/udp \
  -p 6832:6832/udp \
  -p 5778:5778 \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 14250:14250 \
  -p 14268:14268 \
  -p 14269:14269 \
  -p 9411:9411 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.31
```

Here I noticed 2 issues :

**Issue 1**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen udp 0.0.0.0:6832: bind: address already in use.
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen udp 0.0.0.0:6831: bind: address already in use.
```

**Issue 2**

```
My micro service is not showing up in the jaeger UI.
```

Can some one please help me with resolving the issue. Thanks in advance

**Note :**
At this point, I have only single microservice and not trying to connect with other microservice. Is that an issue ?